Lines shapefile with black borders but transparency
In QGIS it is easy to remove fill inside a polygon to only keep black border. For the lines entities removing fill (or apply transparency) will only reveal the black bolder line behind of it that creates a "fake border". Is there a way to create a real border that is not behind the true line to apply transparency?

From QGIS 3.36 onwards there is a new symbole layer type Linefillwhere you can define a normal fill for the line symbol with a transparent fill inside

